# Getting PID of FCGI web2py on shared hosting

Tags: web2py, pid, fastcgi

I followed the instructions on [this page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aobLFODvKZ2YJ%3awww.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1401/web2py-on-shared-hosting-hostmonster-with-fastcgi+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), and got web2py to run with FCGI on my Hostmonster shared hosting. However, I can't find the PID of this web2py server I'm running. (After I ran the server, I forgot to write down its PID.) I'm trying to do `ps aux | grep web2py` as some have suggested, but got nothing. There is also no /var/run/web2pyd.pid file, or any .pid file in /var/run with web2py in it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to find the PID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when the ssh session ends, the web2py server process also ends, since I wasn't detaching the process from the ssh session. You can see what processes belong to your user with:

```
    ps aux | grep `whoami`
```